# App works on API 26 but crashes on API 23 (marshmallow)

Tags: java, android

The application is working as fine without any unexpected behavior in API 26 emulator, but crashes in API 23. The app right when it starts. I'm fairly new to android so not quite sure what changes to make to adapt to API 23.

Here's my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.set.www.assignment_1_mobile"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    }
```

Here's the error log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.set.www.assignment_1_mobile/com.set.www.assignment_1_mobile.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
    at com.set.www.assignment_1_mobile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
    at com.set.www.assignment_1_mobile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
    at com.set.www.assignment_1_mobile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.set.www.assignment_1_mobile:drawable/nyteimg" (7f030004) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f030004 a=-1 r=0x7f030004}
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
    at com.set.www.assignment_1_mobile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Any help will be much appreciated. I hope I have provided enough information, if I haven't, please do let me know. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Here's my main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/nyteimg"
    tools:context="com.setconestoga.www.assignment_1_mobile.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/main_menu"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PlaceOrder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_place_order"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="27dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/settingScreenTitle"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ViewOrders"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtViewOrder"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/VisitWebsite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Visit Website"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="28dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Notes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Feedback"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="29dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ExitButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/exit"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check if you have any warning in the main activity xml file (underlined in yellow) saying that such element is in defined in an api above 23 and that your min sdk is 15.

Comment: Hi Juan, I don't see any warnings at all in main activity xml file. I have even updated the question with my main activity file just in case.

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.set.www.assignment_1_mobile:drawable/nyteimg" (7f030004) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f030004 a=-1 r=0x7f030004}`. Check if this image is proper.

Comment: as @Codebender says, your `nyteimg` is not a correct type of drawable. You need to check it or you can remove the `android:background="@drawable/nyteimg"` from your layout.

Comment: @Codebender, yes i just checked the image, and i don't think anything is wrong with it. I even changed it to a different image, and still the app crashes.

Comment: or probably you're placing the image to `drawable-v26` instead of `drawable-xxx`

Comment: @Codebender I just removed the image rather than replacing it, and it worked. Thanks for the help. Btw could you tell me what was wrong with a jpg image? Is there a specific format needed to have a background? Like bmp or png?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך There's just one drawable resource in my project, if the case is that i have to place it in drawable-v23, how do i go about that?

Comment: each image placed inside drawable-v23 will only work with version 23. So, you need to move it to `drawable` or create multiple image to `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, etc.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך I did as you suggested, moved the images to drawable from drawable-v26. And it worked. It doesn't crash anymore. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Great and Congrats! Let me make it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each image placed inside `drawable-v26` will only work with Android api version **26**. So, you need to move it to `drawable` or create multiple image to drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, etc.